# jQuery UI Background Color Flickers in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, background-color

I'm experiencing issues with IE (of course) and jQuery UI. I'm animating the background color and everything works fine in all other browsers, but for some reason IE flashes different colors while animating. It does the actual background color animation, but is a horrible transition. A ton of different colors randomly flash in during the transition. Has anyone experienced this issue before? Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code or create a fiddle, so that it is going to easy to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, for color transition, jQuery Color Plugin does the job much better. Find it [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/).

Regarding your question, unless you show some codes, can't help you debug that.